# ¿Porqué mockito no puede mockear mi clase?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit-5

Tengo el siguiente servicio:

```
package inventarios.service;

import inventarios.repository.LoginUsersRepository;
import inventarios.to.LoginUser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class LoginUsersService {
    @Autowired
    LoginUsersRepository usersRepository;

    public List<LoginUser> findAll(){
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Y la siguiente prueba unitaria:

```
import inventarios.service.LoginUsersService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
class GUITest {

    @Mock
    private LoginUsersService usersService;

    @InjectMocks
    private LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();

    @Test
    void main() {
        Mockito.when(usersService.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
 }
}
```

Sin embargo al correrla obtengo:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
>
> ```
> Mockito cannot mock this class: class inventarios.service.LoginUsersService.
> ```
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
> If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Mi clase es pública y no es final. ¿Qué podría estar mal?

Comment: Yo también tuve este problema, que versión de Java usas?

Comment: La versión número 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hallé el problema, como menciona [ésta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369559/mockito-cant-mock-an-interface), mockito necesita varias librerías, no únicamente el core, así que remplacé `mockito-core` por `mockito-all` a la última versión estable y funcionó de maravilla.